# Why does this series diverge using Ratio Test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, ratio

So I was working on this problem

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^{100}}$$

After all of my work performing the ratio test, I ended up with a $$\frac{2}{n+1} = 0$$

Therefore, I assumed it absolutely converges, but turns out that it diverges. May I please get an explanation why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you computed the ratio incorrectly. It should be
$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{100}} \cdot \frac{n^{100}}{2^n} = 2 \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{100}$$

Comment: You're right, I did. I cancelled out the n in the numerator. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 4):

A simple remark: you don't even need the ratio test, as this series diverges trivially: its general terù $\frac{2^n}{n^{100}}$ does not tend to $0$ at $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{100}}\frac{n^{100}}{2^n}=\frac{2}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{100}}$$